# Using Realm with RxJava 2

Tags: java, android, realm, rx-java, rx-java2

I am using RxJava 2 in my Android application, and am integrating Realm. As far as I can tell, Realm only supports RxJava 1 by default, and allows an `Observable` to be returned when querying for `RealmResults<?>`, like so:

```
Realm.getDefaultInstance()
    .where(VideoBundle.class)
    .findAll()
    .asObservable()
    .first()
```

The Observable returned is from RxJava 1. How can I use Realm and RxJava 2 together? I have come across 2 relevant issues, found [here](https://github.com/realm/realm-java/issues/3497) and [here](https://github.com/realm/realm-java/issues/4135), but no succinct answer was found. Additionally, the documentation (found here: https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/#rxjava) mentions creating a custom `RxObservableFactory`, but provides no resources on how to do so.

How can Realm be used with a project already using RxJava 2?

Comment: `Realm.getDefaultInstance().where(VideoBundle.class)` hopefully not because you're never closing *that* Realm instance.

Comment: Btw the solution is to wrap Realm's things with Rx2's things, https://github.com/realm/realm-java/issues/3497#issuecomment-275375789

Answer (score 3):

The solution is to wrap RealmResults with Flowable, with LATEST backpressure strategy.

```
private io.reactivex.Flowable<RealmResults<_>> getSomeItems() {
    return io.reactivex.Flowable.create(new FlowableOnSubscribe<RealmResults<__>>() {
        @Override
        public void subscribe(FlowableEmitter<RealmResults<__>> emitter)
                throws Exception {
            Realm realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();
            RealmResults<__> results = realm.where(__.class).findAllSortedAsync("__");

            final RealmChangeListener<RealmResults<__>> listener = _realm -> {
                if(!emitter.isUnsubscribed() && results.isLoaded()) {
                     emitter.onNext(results);
                }
            };
            emitter.setDisposable(Disposables.fromRunnable(() -> {
                results.removeChangeListener(listener);
                realm.close();
            }));
            results.addChangeListener(listener);
        }
    }, BackpressureStrategy.LATEST)
    .subscribeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
    .unsubscribeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread());
```

---

From Realm 4.0.0-RC1 and above, this behavior I showed above is baked in using `realmResults.asFlowable()`.

```
Disposable subscription = realm.where(__.class)
                               .findAllSortedAsync("__")
                               .asFlowable()
                               .filter(RealmResults::isLoaded)
                               .subscribe(...);
```

Comment: I took the 4.0.0-rc1 version and it seems it has the toFlowable in the RealmObject class. So they might have changed it. I am still investigating.

Comment: Not changed, just providing first-party support for this same thing. Don't forget to unsubscribe.

Comment: If you use findFirst instead of findAllSorted there is a potential nullpointer thread.

Comment: @AndreiT that probably contributes to why I used `findAll*` here as an example instead of `findFirst`? Honestly I wouldn't use `findFirst()` like this, only if I know the object actually exists. Even then maybe just using `results.get(0).asFlowable()` is a better option

Comment: I won't, just trying to point out that it is an issue and has to be avoided.

Comment: get(0) still suffers from the same problem potential nullpointer -> check the sources. I used a combination between flowable and maybe.

Comment: why the BackpressureStrategy is LATEST and not BUFFER?
We want to get all data

Comment: @Fakher because it's a RealmResults, so even if you buffer it, you'll just receive the newest data multiple times, no?

Comment: @EpicPandaForce How did you get this `filter(RealmResults::isLoaded)` working? Documentation says "To have a function type with receiver instead, specify the type explicitly:" and AS IDE forces me to explicitly specify a type, like `filter(RealmResults<CustomObject>::isLoaded)`