# How to get Observable with List of objects from Realm using RxJava?

Tags: realm, rx-java, observable, rx-java2

I have only this:

```
public Observable<List<Movie>> getAll() {
    return Observable.just(Movie.class)
            .flatMap(t -> Observable.just(t)
                    .doOnSubscribe(disposable -> realm.executeTransaction(realm1 -> realm1.where(Movie.class).findAll()))
                    .onErrorResumeNext((ObservableSource<? extends Class<Movie>>) observer -> Observable.empty())
                    .map(all -> realm.where(Movie.class).findAll())
            );
}
```

But it looks really ugly))

Everything would be okay, if there where possibilities to avoid duplicate code and save realm.where(Movie.class).findAll() and reuse in map(). RealmResults method addAll is deprecated.

Comment: I think you should read [this](https://academy.realm.io/posts/creating-a-reactive-data-layer-with-realm-and-rxjava2/) and also check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44341905/6774854) answer.

Comment: I don't think, that this will work, because Observable.empty will just emit onComplete. So you will get a observable which does completes.

Comment: @masp thanks for linking my answer, unfortunately the question asker over there just abandoned his question so I can't mark this as duplicate. Sad life...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As also described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44341905/6774854):

```
private io.reactivex.Flowable<List<Movie>> getAll() {
    return io.reactivex.Flowable.create(new FlowableOnSubscribe<List<Movie>>() {
        @Override
        public void subscribe(FlowableEmitter<List<Movie>> emitter)
                throws Exception {
            Realm realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();
            RealmResults<Movie> results = realm.where(Movie.class).findAllAsync();
            final RealmChangeListener<RealmResults<Movie>> listener = _realm -> {
                if(!emitter.isUnsubscribed() && results.isLoaded()) {
                     emitter.onNext(results);
                }
            };
            emitter.setDisposable(Disposables.fromRunnable(() -> {
                results.removeChangeListener(listener);
                realm.close();
            }));
            results.addChangeListener(listener);
        }
    }, BackpressureStrategy.LATEST)
    .subscribeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
    .unsubscribeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread());
```

But as @masp said as a comment, you can read more about designing a reactive data layer using Realm with RxJava2 in [my article about this on realm.io that was published a month ago](https://academy.realm.io/posts/creating-a-reactive-data-layer-with-realm-and-rxjava2/).

So with Realm 4.0.0-RC1 and above, you can actually just do

```
private io.reactivex.Flowable<List<Movie>> getAll(Realm realm) {
    if(realm.isAutoRefresh()) {
        return realm.where(Movie.class)
                .findAllAsync()
                .asFlowable()
                .filter(RealmResults::isLoaded);
    } else { // for background threads
        return Flowable.just(realm.where(Movie.class).findAll());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can always extract the code of find movie in another method to be reused. Even in functional API we should avoid break DRY.

```
public void code() {
    public Observable<List<Movie>> getAll () {
        return Observable.just(Movie.class)
                .flatMap(t -> Observable.just(t)
                        .doOnSubscribe(disposable -> realm.executeTransaction(realm1 -> findMovie((Object) realm1)))
                        .onErrorResumeNext((ObservableSource<? extends Class<Movie>>) observer -> Observable.empty())
                        .map(all -> findMovie((Object) all))
                );
    }

}

private Object findMovie(Object realm1) {
    return realm1.where(Movie.class).findAll();
}
```